# Windows 10 unable to re-allocate Unallocated space

Tags: windows-10, ssd, memory-management

I have 23 Gigs of unallocated space on my SSD card. I would like to extend my default drive so that I can have unused space back (failed linux install attempt).

The problem is the `Extend drive` field is **grayed out** therefore I am unable to preform the operation.

[image: screenshot of the issue]

I was told the field is grayed out only in the case of no allocable space.

What could this issue mean. How could I overcome it?

Any help would be great.

Comment: Show a picture of drive management without that context menu blocking everything. You have another partition there blocking you from expanding C:. Can it be deleted?

Comment: In order to extend the boot partition you will have to delete partition 4.  You don't actually need the recovery partition, and it can be created with a little effort, but how that is accomplished is a different question.

Answer (score -1):

From the image, it seems like you have another partition between your %systemdrive% and the unallocated space blocked from view behind the context menu.

You can extend that blocked from view partition into the unallocated space, but you won't "leapfrog" your %systemdrive% (c:) across already partitioned space.

Whatever the cause, I've avoided this annoyance by using Partition Wizard Free because it's reliable and no hassle w/o registration or SPAM messages that try to establish an ongoing relationship.

PW can resize, reallocate merge partitions such as joining all of your partitions w/o losing data.

After installation, you can just copy the install directory even onto a USB drive and use it as portable application.

**TIP:** Install it or execute from a partition you AREN'T resizing or moving and you'll successfully execute the partition operations inside Windows just like using Disk Manager and without rebooting.

https://www.partitionwizard.com/download.html